# Why is SymmetricDS replication creating multiple rows with the same unique column despite using sync_key_name?

Tags: symmetricds

I am trying to configure SymmetricDS to replicate data from a table that does not have a defined primary key. I have defined the unique column in `sync_key_name` but the replication is still inserting new rows for existing data, resulting in multiple lines containing the same value for the 'unique' column.

Is there any other configuration required to use `sync_key_name` than just entering the field into it?

We initially entered the `sync_key_name` value as lowercase, but corrected it to upper case but we still are getting duplicates. I can't see any other settings that appear relevant to this.

Comment: Could you check if the trigger for the table at the source node has been re-created after correcting to upper case the value of the unique column entered in `sync_key_name`?

Comment: We had removed the trigger after our tests last week. We have added it back today, and I checked the value in SYNC_KEY_NAME (in SYM_TRIGGER on the source DB) and it is uppercase as expected. We ran another replication and it still duplicated the existing records.

Comment: Should the SYNC_KEY_NAME setting be reflected in the SYM_ON_I.. and SYM_ON_U.. triggers?

Comment: Do you have an autoincrement primary key in the table in the destination mode?

Comment: No, neither the source or destination tables have defined primary keys, though there is a column is (should) be a unique defacto pk.

Comment: It's strange that there's no unique column constraint exception in the destination node when another row with the same value is inserted by the synchronisation mechanism. Are you sure there's an unique column constraint?

Comment: No sorry, I have given you the wrong impression. There are no constraints on this table other than some not null constraints. A column is intended to be unique (and is with normal software use) but is not constrained to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS will not add constraints to your target table. The `sync_key_names` setting determines the columns that SymmetricDS will use in the where clause when it replicates a delete or an update statement. When you send a load, the data comes through via insert statements. If you run a load multiple times, then it will send the same rows again and the target table will contain duplicate rows.

Comment: Oh I would have expected it to send update statements where the data already exists. The documentation for sync_key_names suggests that how it works.